# Unreal Engine 4 - Disabling analog input ONLY in the umg widget

Tags: input, controller, widget, unreal-engine4, disable

How to disable analog input ONLY in the umg widget itself and still keep the input for the game character?
A good example of the menu that I am asking about is the one like in game Dark Souls, where you instead of pausing the game, when opening menu still have full control over your character with the analog stick, and control over the menu with the directional buttons.

I have tried overriding the "On Analog Value Changed" function in the widget but that for some reason disables the analog controls for the character, and not the widget, the widget can still be controlled with the left analog stick, so I got the opposite result from the one I wanted.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have overridden?